# Peculiar deprotonation of an alkenyl proton

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

In [this](https://www.synarchive.com/syn/304) synthesis of Punctatin A, there is this peculiar deprotonation step. When subjected to the base $\ce {NaH}$, we would expect deprotonation at the $\alpha$-position, at the side opposite to the double bond. However, what is observed here is, in fact, the deprotonation at the double bond. Not only is the $\ce {C(sp^2)-H}$ bond stronger, there is also no delocalisation of the negative charge in the conjugate base that is produced. Note that the lone pair in the carbanion conjugate base is held in an $\ce {sp^2}$ hybrid orbital that is perpendicular to the $\ce {p}$ orbitals of the enone $\pi$ system. Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Decided to convert this to an answer anyway. Disclaimer: I'm not an organic chemist (anymore), and corrections/suggestions are more than welcome.

One distinct mechanistic possibility here is that you deprotonate γ to the carbonyl, then the extended enolate reacts at the position you see, and then after that there's some tautomerisation which brings the double bond back into conjugation with the carbonyl (maybe during workup).

[image: Putative mechanism]

These are specific conditions under which you might expect deprotonation at the γ-position over the other α-position. In particular, the extended enolate resulting from this is more stable than the cross-conjugated enolate resulting from α-deprotonation, so this is called the *"thermodynamic enolate"*. Paquette *et al.* use this term in the paper ([*J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1987,** *109* (10), 3017–3024](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00244a025)):

> Toward this end, the thermodynamic enolate of **6b** was exposed to [...] 1-bromo-2-methylpropane.

I won't comment on the specifics of this reaction, but will mention that it can be [very dangerous if scaled up](https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2019/08/14/sodium-hydride-in-aprotic-solvents-look-out).

If you wanted to deprotonate the other α-position, you would probably have more success with something like LDA. That deprotonation relies on chelation of the carbonyl oxygen to lithium (via a cyclic transition state*), so goes for the proton nearer to the carbonyl. That would be the "kinetic enolate".

[image: Enolates]

---

* The six-membered chair-like transition state is widely taught, but is actually of questionable accuracy in this specific case. I think the transition state *is* cyclic, but is eight-membered or something like that. See e.g. slides 50 onwards of this very informative presentation from David Macmillan's group: [*"Lies My Sophomore Organic
Professor Told Me"*](http://chemlabs.princeton.edu/macmillan/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/CRJ_Lies.pdf).

Comment: What can we say about the proton acidity at the gamma position compared to the alpha position at the other side? While in theory, resonance structures can be drawn for the conjugate base resulting from gamma deprotonation, illustrating extensive delocalisation of the lone pair, I am slightly skeptical of the significance of these resonance forms as the oxygen atom and gamma carbon are 3 atoms apart.

Comment: Resonance doesn't really care that much whether the oxygen is one or three bonds away, as long as there's an intervening π system. I think the easiest way of looking at it is to not overcomplicate it - pKa reflects the HA/A- equilibrium, and since HA in this case is the same compound, pKa is a direct reflection of the conjugate base stability. The system with linear conjugation is more stable than the one with cross conjugation, unless there's a significant difference in e.g. ring strain which I don't think is the case here.

Comment: ... But I'm not sure exactly how different the pKa values are. Might be worth a computation...

Comment: That's a relatively low yield for an alkylation, it would be interesting to know what the other products are - whether there is a significant amount of the alpha alkylation product

Comment: @Waylander, apparently with an allylic iodide they get 40% desired product + 20% dialkylation of the extended enolate at the alpha position (hence the double bond can't move back into conjugation) - but no comment on the reaction with the plain alkyl iodide (they say "exclusive formation of 15", 15 being the desired product)

Comment: While Scheme III shows alkylation with 1-bromo-2-methylpropane, the experimental section employs the iodide. Alkylation occurs (54%) with recovery of a lesser amount of recovered starting enone. With the non-allylic electrophile, reconjugation is faster than double alkylation.