# Regioselective enolate formation, choosing major and minor products

Tags: organic-chemistry, regioselectivity, enolate-chemistry

This question came in my organic chem assignment. The options highlighted are the answers.

The end carbon(adjacent to the carbonyl group) should have more acidic alpha-hydrogen and the alkene formed is more substituted (as compared to the one in F). Still it is given as the minor product. Could someone explain why?

[image]

Comment: The regioselectivity depends on the conditions that you use. See e.g. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/132890/16683 or https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/17103/16683. The major product here is the so-called "thermodynamic enolate".

Comment: The original question here is somewhat misleading in that it assumes that these are the only two products. There is E-/Z- isomerism in what's labelled here the "major" product that must also be accounted for.

Comment: @orthocresol, thanks for the links. 
I understand that the removal of the gamma hydrogen results in resonance (leading to a stable product). However, shouldn't the fact that E has more substituted alkene also come into play?

Comment: But, in E one double bond is trisubstituted and the other disubstituted, and in F the same is true. Based on that, I don't see why the alkene substitution should affect the overall stability all that much. You would need a significant effect to overcome the preexisting bias, which favours extended conjugation (F) over cross-conjugation (E). Agreed about E/Z isomers; that's a separate issue, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A major factor contributing to the stability of the enolate ion formed as the major product (F) is the stability associated with *extended conjugation* or *extended delocalisation* via *resonance*. Due to this, terming (F) as the major product seems justified.

If the product were to be a *kinetically-controlled* one (KCP), then the presence of three acidic alpha hydrogen atoms could've caused *faster* formation of product (E) ; it *still* would **not** have been the more stable product, but since the major product in KCP-type reactions is controlled more by the *kinetics* , rather than the *thermodynamics*, we would possibly expect to see (E) in a larger yield in that case.

***Note:*** Strictly speaking, the problem should mention conditions that can help us to *unambiguously* determine which pathway (KCP vs. TCP) should be chosen. But a practical advice, garnered from the experience of working problems which seldom perfectly mention the reaction conditions, is that unless mentioned otherwise, it is always wise to *first* consider the thermodynamically stable product.